# When using lxml, can the XML be rendered without namespace attributes?

Tags: python, lxml

I am generating some XML with lxml and getting nodes generated like this:

```
<QBXML xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
py:pytype="TREE">
```

and:

```
<MaxReturned py:pytype="int">
```

These custom attributes are killing Quickbooks' parser.  Can I get LXML to render without the custom stuff?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the following take care of it:

```
objectify.deannotate(root, xsi_nil=True)
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
```

or, if using lxml >= 2.3.2 (thanks @Pedru):

```
objectify.deannotate(root, cleanup_namespaces=True, xsi_nil=True)
```

Comment: from lxml version 2.3.2 you can pass `cleanup_namespaces=True` to `objectify.deannotate()` (no need to call `etree.cleanup_namespaces()`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have nested XML you can do this:

```
from lxml import objectify
doc = objectify.ElementMaker(annotate=False)
doc = (objectify.E.configuration(getattr(objectify.E,'networklists'),name="acl.conf",description="Network Lists"))
objectify.deannotate(doc,cleanup_namespaces=True)
```

The output with custom attributes is like this:

```
<configuration description="Network Lists" name="acl.conf">
<network-lists>

</network-lists>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you're using

```
etree.fromstring(xml_response)
```

then doing this:

```
xml_response.replace(' xmlns:', ' xmlnamespace:').replace(' xmlns=', ' xmlnamespace=')
```

avoids it ever parsing namespaces