# Unwanted namespace declaration in lxml XPath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I want to select the first child of particular element (`subelement`), but this child's namespace is  different from parent's namespace. Moreover, this child can be of any namespace.

```
xml = '''<root xmlns="default_ns">
    <subelement>
        <!-- here we can have an element of any namespace  -->
        <some_prefix:a xmlns:some_prefix="some_namespace">
            <some_prefix:b/>
        </some_prefix:a>
    </subelement>
</root>'''
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
evaluator = etree.XPathEvaluator(root, namespaces={'def':'default_ns'})
child = evaluator.evaluate('//def:subelement/child::*')[0]
a_string = etree.tostring(child)
print a_string
```

This gives:

```
<some_prefix:a xmlns:some_prefix="some_namespace" xmlns="default_ns">
    <some_prefix:b/>
</some_prefix:a>
```

but what I want to get is child without namespace declaration from parent `xmlns="default_ns"`:

```
<some_prefix:a xmlns:some_prefix="some_namespace">
    <some_prefix:b/>
</some_prefix:a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Dimitre* completely explained why namespaces are inherited and how to get rid of it using XSLT.

I've used **deepcopy** from [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to remove unwanted namespace.

This is the my final solution using Python:

```
from lxml import etree
from copy import deepcopy

xml = '''<root xmlns="default_ns">
    <subelement>
        <!-- here we can have an element of any namespace  -->
        <some_prefix:a xmlns:some_prefix="some_namespace">
            <some_prefix:b/>
        </some_prefix:a>
    </subelement>
</root>'''
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
evaluator = etree.XPathEvaluator(root, namespaces={'def':'default_ns'})
child = evaluator.evaluate('//def:subelement/child::*')[0]
child = deepcopy(child)
a_string = etree.tostring(child)
print a_string
```

Answer (score 1):

> but what I want to get is child without namespace declaration from
>   parent xmlns="default_ns".

**This is not possible to achieve by only evaluating an XPath expression.**

**In XML any element inherits all of its parent's namespace nodes**, unless it redefines a particular namespace.

**This means that `some_prefix:a` inherits the default namespace `"default_ns"`** from its parent (`subelement`), which itself inherits this same default namespace node from the top element `root`.

XPath is a query language for XML documents. As such, it only helps select nodes, but **the evaluation of an XPath expression never destroys, adds or alters nodes, including namespace nodes**.

Because of this, the default namespace node that belongs to `some_prefix:a` cannot be destroyed as result of the evaluation of your XPath expression -- thus this namespace node is shown when `some_prefix:a` is serialized to text.

**Solution**: Use your favorite PL that hosts XPath, to delete the unwanted namespace node.

**For example, if the hosting language is XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:d="default_ns">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="delNS"
    select="/*/d:subelement/*[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="delNS">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="delNS" select="node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root xmlns="default_ns">
    <subelement>
        <!-- here we can have an element of any namespace  -->
        <some_prefix:a xmlns:some_prefix="some_namespace">
            <some_prefix:b/>
        </some_prefix:a>
    </subelement>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<some_prefix:a xmlns:some_prefix="some_namespace">
   <some_prefix:b/>
</some_prefix:a>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre! Actually I want to achieve the result using lxml. After your anwser I found [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365422/python-lxml-adds-unused-namespaces) and the first comment in [this anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6365981/629762) suggest how to do this using deepcopy and clean_namespaces: `child = deepcopy(child) etree.cleanup_namespaces(child)`

Comment: @Marcin Are those two different commands? Also, my interpreter says "'deepcopy' is not defined".

Comment: @NoBugs These are two seperate commands. Moreover, I found that `etree.cleanup_namespaces` is needless. Use only `deepcopy` to remove unwanted namespace. `deepcopy` function comes from [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module. This is the final code: 
    child = evaluator.evaluate('//def:subelement/child::*')[0]    
    child = deepcopy(child)
    a_string = etree.tostring(child)