# Remove default namespace from lxml etree

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

I've read [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232031/how-can-i-strip-namespaces-out-of-an-lxml-tree) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159221/remove-namespace-and-prefix-from-xml-in-python-using-lxml) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141464/stripping-python-namespace-attributes-from-an-lxml-objectify-objectifiedelement) about removing namespaces from an `lxml.etree` but none of them seems to work on default namespace (`xmlns:blahblahblah`).

How can I remove the default namespace? It has no use for my XML processing needs and I don't want to have to continually pass in a namespace map into `somenode.xpath('.//default:sometag', namespaces=my_annoying_namespace_map)`

```
>>> from lxml import etree, objectify
>>> xml = etree.fromstring('''<forest xmlns="idontcare.com">
<tree><branch><leaf>bill</leaf></branch><branch><leaf>bob</leaf></branch></tree>
<tree><branch><leaf>sue</leaf></branch></tree></forest>''')
>>> xml
<Element {idontcare.com}forest at 0x2aa0288>
>>> objectify.deannotate(xml, cleanup_namespaces=True)
>>> xml
<Element {idontcare.com}forest at 0x2aa0288>
>>>
```

The method [suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232031/how-can-i-strip-namespaces-out-of-an-lxml-tree) doesn't work because there is no prefix on elements with default namespaces.

```
def strip_ns_prefix(tree):
    #iterate through only element nodes (skip comment node, text node, etc) :
    for element in tree.xpath('descendant-or-self::*'):
        #if element has prefix...
        if element.prefix:
            #replace element name with it's local name
            element.tag = etree.QName(element).localname
    return tree
```

Comment: sigh. https://bugs.python.org/issue18304

Comment: oh, never mind, the 2nd method in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232031/how-can-i-strip-namespaces-out-of-an-lxml-tree works.