# Remove "xmlns:py..." with lxml.objectify

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I just discovered `lxml.objectify` which seems nice and easy for reading/writing simple XML files.

Firstly, is it a good idea to use `lxml.objectify`? For instance is it mature and still developed and likely to be available in the future?

Secondly, how do I prevent `objectify` from addding markup like `xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" py:pytype="str"` in the output below ?.

---

**Input : config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>
  <MyElement1>sdfsdfdsfd</MyElement1>
</Test>
```

---

**Code**

```
from lxml import etree, objectify

with open('config.xml') as f:
    xml = f.read()
root = objectify.fromstring(xml)

root.Information = 'maybe'

print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

---

**Output**

```
<Test>
  <MyElement1>sdfsdfdsfd</MyElement1>
  <Information xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" py:pytype="str">maybe</Information>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out here : [When using lxml, can the XML be rendered without namespace attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084730/when-using-lxml-can-the-xml-be-rendered-without-namespace-attributes), this is enough to prevent this `xmlns` markup to appear :

```
objectify.deannotate(root, xsi_nil=True)
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)
```

Comment: from lxml version 2.3.2 you can pass `cleanup_namespaces=True` to `objectify.deannotate()` (no need to call `etree.cleanup_namespaces()`)